# Can you speed up mysqlcheck by tweaking my.cnf?

Tags: mysql, performance

Can you speed up mysqlcheck by tweaking my.cnf?

And if so, what is it exactly one might want to tweak?

I have a table that takes over 1 hour to just check/repair.
My site is down for that time, as the table is locked while checking/repairing.

If I bring the site down, so db-access is minimized, can I affect the check/repair performance by tweaking my.cnf?

Comment: Why does it need checking/repairing in the first place?

Comment: I ended up discovering the partition was full ant the temporary file for repairing was growing too big, causing me to wait forever (or at least until I discovered the partition was full). But still, for future reference I would like to know how to speed up checking/repairing in general, to minimize down-time.